# npm start is not working for React app on Gulp js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, gulp

I have been started working on React.js App running on Gulp environment using node modules.

To run the project command is **npm start** or **gulp watch**.

Among those npm start will trigger the gulp watch, so when I use the npm start getting some kind of node module error. If I use gulp watch not getting below error.

[Command Prompt Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NCgnK.png)

```
C:\Users\ryangyeswar\Documents\Interserv>npm start
'CALL "C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node_modules
\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" prefix -g' is not recognized as an internal or external com
mand,
operable program or batch file.

> react-starterify@0.0.4 start C:\Users\ryangyeswar\Documents\Interserv
> gulp watch


npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\
node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
npm ERR! node v4.8.4
npm ERR! npm  v2.15.11
npm ERR! file C:\Users\ryangyeswar\AppData\Roaming\npm
npm ERR! path C:\Users\ryangyeswar\AppData\Roaming\npm
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn C:\Users\ryangyeswar\AppData\Roaming\npm
npm ERR! react-starterify@0.0.4 start: `gulp watch`
npm ERR! spawn C:\Users\ryangyeswar\AppData\Roaming\npm ENOENT
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the react-starterify@0.0.4 start script 'gulp watch'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the react-starterify package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     gulp watch
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs react-starterify
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!
npm ERR!     npm owner ls react-starterify
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\
node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
npm ERR! node v4.8.4
npm ERR! npm  v2.15.11
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! react-starterify@0.0.4 start: `gulp watch`
npm ERR! Exit status -4058
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the react-starterify@0.0.4 start script 'gulp watch'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the react-starterify package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     gulp watch
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs react-starterify
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!
npm ERR!     npm owner ls react-starterify
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\ryangyeswar\Documents\Interserv\npm-debug.log
```

**2)** while checking the npm version same error occured **npm -v**

[npm command error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LJZU6.png)

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade your `node` & `npm` version. First uninstall npm using `npm uninstall`. Then update node and npm both. Check https://nodejs.org/en/ for latest available version for your machine. Ideally you should be using node above 6.x and npm above 3.x version. If the problem still persists, please share the npm start script from your `package.json`.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Actually my project has been developed in node version 4 , it will runs only on that environment.so i installed 4.8.4

Comment: Can you reboot your system so that the environment variable path is set correctly in case its not already and try!